# button:not(:disabled) { cursor:pointer; } what does it mean?

Tags: css, disabled-input

Hye,

```
button:not(:disabled) { 
cursor:pointer;
}
```

what does it mean? The focus is possible or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that if your cursor is over any `<button>` tags that aren't disabled it will appear as a pointer.

`button` is the HTML element that the styling is being applied to. `:not()` means that the element can't have the attributes followed in the parameter. `cursor: pointer` turns the cursor to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If your `button` is not **disabled**, it will have `cursor:pointer;` attributes